# securing a page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to build a jquery mobile application with a few pages that are mildly secured with password protection. I'm assuming that I can put something in one of the page events to redirect but I cant seem to get it working cleanly. I can get the redirect to happen but it first flashes the page that I am trying to protect.

Here is the most promising thing that  I tried:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#ProtectedPage", function (event) {

        if (!hasUserLoggedIn()) {
              alert("You must be logged in to visit this page");
              event.preventDefault()     

              $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#loginpage" );
         }

});
```

thanks for any help that you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to do a true redirect to the login page on pagebeforechange instead:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (event, data) {

        if (!hasUserLoggedIn()) {
              alert("You must be logged in to visit this page");
              data.toPage = "#loginpage";
              $.extend(data.options, {changeHash: false});
         }

});
```

Note: jQuery Mobile >= 1.4.3 has deprecated event by a similar one

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (event, data) {

    if (!hasUserLoggedIn()) {
          alert("You must be logged in to visit this page");
          data.toPage = "#loginpage";
          $.extend(data.options, {changeHash: false});
     }

})
```

;

http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/pagecontainerbeforechange/

Comment: That's a good start but it has two issues from my perspective. First, It's using a deprecated method that I would like to avoid. I  can deal with that but it also protects every page while I only want to protect a couple of them. Is there a way of protecting a subset of pages? I read the docs on this event and Im not seeing  data.fromPage

Comment: Added the replacement event for jQuery 1.4.3+.... (in fact example was from this new event). This event launches before navigation to a potentially insecure page, so the approach to put this event to document level is correct. Protects every illegal navigation inside the app.

Comment: Yes this works. In order for it to suit my needs (only securing  a subset of pages) I had to examine and break up data.absUrl like in the referenced article. Thank you so much for the answer.